# Removing non-utf characters using php5

Tags: php, utf-8

I am trying to display data on a webpage that contains non-utf8 characters.  A user uploads a tab separated file from a FileMaker databse into our Oracle database via a web form.  I then display the data through another user webpage.

One record has a character I've not seen before.  It is the letters, 'VT' in a square. Sort of like [VT].  Pasting here, but it probably wont show in this setting.  attaching image.  If it does not show, the line of text with the character in it looks like this:

```
'Blue is a color[VT]Blue web page to find more information.[VT]Blue is a nice color'

![vt character](http://www.johndcowan.com/graphics/vt-special-chars.png)
```

I've tried these PHP functions with no luck:

```
$answer = iconv("utf-8", "utf-8//ignore", $answer);
$answer = htmlspecialchars($answer);
$answer = strip_tags($answer);
```

Anyone have an idea how to 86 this character?

Comment: Just dawned on me.  Maybe it is a Vertical Tab character.  None the less, it is causing my page to bomb. Sigh.

Comment: Well, it's a valid UTF-8 character. Just maybe not one you're prepared  to handle. Figure out what byte it is specifically with `echo bin2hex($answer)`.